# Get the ancestral data from database dynamically

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I would like to get the ancestral or child data when I pass the value in a function.

This is my data from MySQL table.

[image]

If I pass the value of **Document2** in my function i want to get the ancestral data, for example, if I pass **Document2** it will get the ***`Book2`*** then the **Book2** will get the ***`Document1`*** and **Document1** will get the ***`Book1`*** and so on, then same with the **Profile1** it will get the ***`Document0`*** dynamically.

Here's my code.

```
$binded  = array('Document2');
$sources = [];
foreach ($binded as $document) {
    $check = $this->db->where('binded',$document)
                      ->get('binded_document');

    $results = $check->result();
    foreach($results as $key => $result){
         array_push($sources, $result->source);

         $ancestral = $this->db->where('binded',$result->source)
                               ->get('binded_document');

         $ancestrals = $ancestral->result();
         foreach($ancestrals as $k => $r){
              array_push($sources, $r->source);
         }
    }
}
```

The problem with my code is it will not dynamically get ancestral data if the passed value in the function has more than 2 ancestral.

Comment: Sorry, yes im using codeigniter sorry for not tagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f5ea88524efc7d0853b2dd7c22869175)

- I did choose to separate the recursive parts with a `-`.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT 
      source as s, 
      CAST(Binded AS CHAR(1024)) as b,
      1 as c
   FROM table1 WHERE Binded='Document2'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT table1.source, CONCAT(cte.s,'-',cte.b), c+1
   FROM cte
   LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.Binded = cte.s
   WHERE c<10 AND NOT cte.s IS NULL
)
select b
from cte 
where cte.s is null and NOT b is null
group by b
;
```

output:

| b |
| --- |
| Document0-Profile1-Document2 |
| Book1-Document1-Book2-Document2 |

Comment: Thank you for this i make this as a stored proc then explode the results in PHP.